# Let $A$ be a $5\times 5$ complex matrix with characteristic polynomial that is $p(x)=(x-\lambda)^5$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

Let $A$ be a $5\times 5$ complex matrix with characteristic polynomial that is $p(x)=(x-\lambda)^5$.

I've found that 
$$\dim\ker(A-\lambda I)=2$$
$$\dim\ker(A-\lambda I)^2=3$$
$$\dim\ker(A-\lambda I)^3=4$$
and
$$\dim\ker(A-\lambda I)^4=5$$

How can I know that $A$'s Jordan form is
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
\lambda & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\
0 & \lambda & 1 & 0 &0 \\
0  & 0 & \lambda & 1 &0 \\
0  & 0  &0& \lambda & 1 \\
0  & 0  &0& 0 & \lambda \\
\end{array}\right)$$
and not 
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
\lambda & 1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\
0 & \lambda & 0 & 0 &0 \\
0  & 0 & \lambda & 1 &0 \\
0  & 0  &0& \lambda & 1 \\
0  & 0  &0& 0 & \lambda \\
\end{array}\right)?$$

Is that because $\dim\ker (A-\lambda I)^i-\dim\ker(A-\lambda I)^{i-1}=1$ for $i=2,3,4$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Uniqueness .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the nullity of the generalised eigenspace of index $4$ and index $3$ tells us that there is one Jordan block of degree at least $4$, i.e. there is one $J_{\lambda , 4}$ block. In your second matrix there is no $4 \times 4$ Jordan block, so that cannot be the correct form.